# .Net web application behind a WebSeal reverse proxy

Tags: asp.net, .net-3.5, .net-4.0, reverse-proxy, webseal

We are currently designing a solution that will run as a .Net Web application behind a WebSeal reverse proxy.

I have seen some comments on the net where people have had various problems with this, for example rewriting of viewstate.

Question is: Has anyone implemented this combination of techologies and got it to work?

Comment: Have you run into any other snags?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I initially has some issues with the ASP.Net app when accessed through WebSeal. I was running the site on a development server. What worked for me was to deploy the application with debugging turned off in the config file.

```
<compilation debug="false" ...>
```

With debugging turned on, there were some AJAX calls that would work fine when I accessed the site directly but would fail when access through WebSeal. Once I turned the debugging off, everything work fine.

Also, because WebSeal requires anonymous authentication, we couldn't have used Windows Authentication.

Answer (score 8):

I made an ASP.NET application workin behind WEBSEAL. After lot of study and development and test it works.

I suggest some issues to help you:

### IIS and ASP.NET are case insensitive

("...Login.aspx" and "...login.aspx" both lead to the same page); by default webseal is case sensitive. So you should **set WEBSEAL junction to be *case insensitive*** or check any single link (page, javascript, image)

### Internal links, written as *server relative URLs* won't be served

WEBSEAL changes any link referring your application but doesn't change links to other applications. 
 Internal links, written as *server relative URLs* instead of *application relative URLs* won't be changed (WEBSEAL doesn't recognize it's the same application) and won't be served (WEBSEAL rejects links that are not modified).
First rule is to **check any single link and make it an application relative URL** .
Look at rendered HTML if you find  `<.. href=/ anything>` : this i a server relative URL and it is bad.
Look in the Code Behind if you use `"= ~/ anything"` it is good. If you use   `"= / anything"` OR `ResolveUrl(..)` it is bad.

But this is not enough: AJAX puts loads of javascript and code inside *ScriptResource.axd* and *WebResource.axd* and creates server relative URL to link it. This links are not controlled by programmers and there is no easy way to change them.
Easy solution (if possible): solve the problem **setting WEBSEAL junction to be *transparent***.
Hard solution: write the following code (thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5536536/change-the-requested-url-of-webresource-axd/5538530#5538530))

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Initialises my dirty hack to remove the leading slash from all web reference files.
        Response.Filter = new WebResourceResponseFilter(Response.Filter);
    }

public class WebResourceResponseFilter : Stream
{
    private Stream baseStream;

    public WebResourceResponseFilter(Stream responseStream)
    {
        if (responseStream == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("ResponseStream");
        baseStream = responseStream;
    }

    public override bool CanRead
    { get { return baseStream.CanRead; } }

    public override bool CanSeek
    { get { return baseStream.CanSeek; } }

    public override bool CanWrite
    { get { return baseStream.CanWrite; } }

    public override void Flush()
    { baseStream.Flush(); }

    public override long Length
    { get { return baseStream.Length; } }

    public override long Position
    {
        get { return baseStream.Position; }
        set { baseStream.Position = value; }
    }

    public override int Read(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
    { return baseStream.Read(buffer, offset, count); }

    public override long Seek(long offset, System.IO.SeekOrigin origin)
    { return baseStream.Seek(offset, origin); }

    public override void SetLength(long value)
    { baseStream.SetLength(value); }

    public override void Write(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
    {
        //Get text from response stream.
        string originalText = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer, offset, count);

        //Alter the text.
        originalText = originalText.Replace(HttpContext.Current.Request.ApplicationPath + "/WebResource.axd",
            VirtualPathUtility.MakeRelative(HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsolutePath, "~/WebResource.axd"));
        originalText = originalText.Replace(HttpContext.Current.Request.ApplicationPath + "/ScriptResource.axd",
            VirtualPathUtility.MakeRelative(HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsolutePath, "~/ScriptResource.axd"));

        //Write the altered text to the response stream.
        buffer = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(originalText);
        this.baseStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

    }
```

This intercepts the stream to the page and replaces all occurrences of "/WebResource.axd" or "ScriptResource.axd" with "../../WebResource.axd" and "../../ScriptResource.axd"

### Develop code to get actual WEBSEAL user

WEBSEAL has been configured to put username inside *HTTP_IV_USER*. I created *Webseal\Login.aspx* form to read it programmatically.
Now, in order to make this user the CurrentUser I put an hidden *asp.Login*

```
<span style="visibility:hidden"> 
<asp:Login ID="Login1" runat="server" DestinationPageUrl="~/Default.aspx">..
```

and clicked the button programmatically

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string username = Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_IV_USER"];
    (Login1.FindControl("Password") as TextBox).Text = MyCustomProvider.PswJump;
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(username))
    {
        (Login1.FindControl("UserName") as TextBox).Text = username;
        Button btn = Login1.FindControl("LoginButton") as Button;
        ((IPostBackEventHandler)btn).RaisePostBackEvent(null);
     }
    else
    {
        lblError.Text = "Login error.";
    }
}
```

When *LoginButton* fires, application reads UserName (set from WEBSEAL variable) and password (hard coded). So i [**implemented a custom membership provider**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/44w5aswa.aspx) that validates users and sets current Principal.

### Changes in web.config

[loginUrl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.formsauthentication.loginurl.aspx) is the URL for the login page that the FormsAuthentication class will redirect to. It has been set to WEBSEAL portal: not authenticated user and logout button will redirect to portal.

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="https://my.webseal.portal/" defaultUrl="default.aspx"...."/>
</authentication>
```

Since *Webseal/login.aspx* is NOT default login page, [authorization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8d82143t.aspx) tag grants access to not authenticated users:

```
<location path="Webseal/login.aspx">
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <allow users="*"/>
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
</location>
```

Application is set to use custom membership providers:

```
 <membership defaultProvider="MyCustomMembershipProvider">
  <providers>
    <add name="MyCustomMembershipProvider" type="MyNamespace.MyCustomMembershipProvider" connectionStringName="LocalSqlServer"/>
  </providers>
</membership>
<roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="MyCustomRoleProvider">
  <providers>
    <add name="MyCustomRoleProvider" type="MyNamespace.MyCustomRoleProvider" connectionStringName="LocalSqlServer"/>
  </providers>
</roleManager>
```

Debug is set to off:

```
<compilation debug="false" targetFramework="4.0">
```

### that's all folks!